# gnuplot, How to connect points with multiple lines in 3D from a file?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm not familiar with gnuplot, so I'm really getting hard time to deal with it. I know how to plot as 3D and use columns for variables.

Anyway, my question is how to connect points which have the same distance values, but connect those in order of rank below. For example, my file has the information below ;

```
#ID Rank Diatance   x   y   z
25   2    50        13  14  39
34   1    50        19  90  23
23   3    50        54  87  12
48   1    143       78  40  36
38   5    143       10  76  54
96   4    143       64  76  88
104  3    143       19  82  74
201  2    143       30  89  47
76   1    604       103 298 263
97   2    604       111 103 133
87   4    604       215 222 132
109  5    604       175 184 158
283  3    604       102 108 155
294  6    604       530 456 384
```

You see there are 3 different distances and 3 groups of each distance have own ranks. What I want to do is to connect those points that have the same distance values only(the 3rd column), but simultaneously I want to make those being connected in order of rank(the 2nd column), so the expected result I think is that in 3D plot, there are only 3 lines(or curves).

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the data file first by distance, then by rank, and insert blank lines whenever the distance value changes. I'm not sure if you can do all this from within gnuplot, but on a unix-ish system you can easily invoke standard tools to do that for you:

```
splot "<cat test.dat | sort -n -k 3 -k 2 | awk '{if ($3 != olddistance) {print \"\"}; print; olddistance=$3}'" u 4:5:6 w lp
```

[image]

If you want different colors for the lines that connect each group you can use

```
splot "<cat test.dat | sort -n -k 3 -k 2 | awk '{if ($3 != olddistance) {print \"\"}; print; olddistance=$3}'" u 4:5:6:-1 w lp lc variable
```

Comment: ahh.. I'm using Windows, so just like you said, it's hard for me to do this. And even I tried to do with your code, it didn't work at all :( I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know more about the background of this plotting challenge. What is it for?
Yes, you can do it with *gnuplot-only* (hence platform-independent), however, gnuplot itself is really bad at sorting. Actually, it doesn't *want* to be good, you are supposed to use external tools for simple sorting of internal data. From gnuplot 5.4.0 on, you have `zsort` (check `help zsort`), but which is also [not a really good way of sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67801386/7295599).

Nevertheless, there is a cumbersome workaround to sort within gnuplot. It requires gnuplot>=5.2.0 since it's using indexing of datablocks.

For your task, I assume that the data is already sorted in column 3.
The script below does the following:

- adds the row number in front of the line
- inserts empty lines when colunn 3 value changes
- sorts the lines (each block separately) by (former) column 2 (now column 3) via `smooth freq` (check `help smooth`)
- prints the data in new order to the datablock `$Sorted`
- plots the data colored by pseudocolumn -1 (check `help pseudocolumns`) as you have empty lines between the subblocks

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### plot points (dis)connected in a sorted way
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#ID Rank Diatance   x   y   z
25   2    50        13  14  39
34   1    50        19  90  23
23   3    50        54  87  12
48   1    143       78  40  36
38   5    143       10  76  54
96   4    143       64  76  88
104  3    143       19  82  74
201  2    143       30  89  47
76   1    604       103 298 263
97   2    604       111 103 133
87   4    604       215 222 132
109  5    604       175 184 158
283  3    604       102 108 155
294  6    604       530 456 384
EOD

# add empty lines when column 3 changes
set print $Temp1
    v1 = NaN
    do for [i=2:|$Data|] {
        v0 = v1
        v1 = real(word($Data[i],3))
        if (v0!=v1) { print ""}
        print sprintf("%d  ",i).$Data[i]  # add row index in front
    }
set print 
# sort by column 3 (former column 2)
set table $Temp2
    plot $Temp1 u 3:1 smooth freq
unset table
# re-print $Temp2 in sorted order
set print $Sorted
    do for [i=5:|$Temp2|] {
        if (strlen($Temp2[i])>0) { print $Data[int(word($Temp2[i],2))] }
        else { print "" }
    }
set print

set key noautotitle
set xyplane relative 0
set ytics 100
set grid x,y
set view 65,16
set colorsequence classic

splot $Sorted u 4:5:6:(column(-1)+1) w lp pt 7 lc var lw 2, \
           '' u 4:5:6:(column(-1)+1) w p  pt 7 lc var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]