# Unexpected behavior of `zsort` in gnuplot

Tags: sorting, gnuplot

I don't understand the following behavior of `zsort` (check `help zsort`).
If I have a dataset containing `NaN` in the second column and I `zsort` by the first column, why does gnuplot not sort it the expected way, i.e. sorting by first column and the original values in the second column?

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.4)

```
### unexpected behavior of zsort
reset session

$Data <<EOD
4   14.0
6   16.0
3   13.0
5   NaN
2   12.0
7   17.0
8   NaN
1   11.0
9   NaN
EOD

set table $Test
    plot $Data u 1:2:1 smooth zsort
unset table
print $Test
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 8 points
# Curve title: "$Data u 1:2:1"
# x y type
 3  13  i
 4  14  i
 6  16  i
 5  NaN  u
 2  12  i
 7  17  i
 8  NaN  u
 1  11  i
```

Apparently, the datablock gets separated in subblocks when the second column contains `NaN` and the subblocks are sorted separately. And row `9  NaN u` at the end gets suppressed.

**Expected result:**

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 8 points
# Curve title: "$Data u 1:2:1"
# x y type
 1  11  i
 2  12  i
 3  13  i
 4  14  i
 5  NaN  u
 6  16  i
 7  17  i
 8  NaN  u
 9  NaN  u
```

Is there maybe a way to get this expected result?

Comment: ... and `set datafile missing NaN` will sort "correctly" but will remove the `NaN`s completely. But I'd like to keep them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seriously mis-using zsort, which was intended for a very different purpose.  Having said that, I think the variant below may be close enough to what you ask for that you could use it. It moves your original column 2 into column 3 (version 5.4) or column 4 (version 6), but whatever you were going to do next with the sorted data should be able to find it there.

```
$Data <<EOD
4   14.0
6   16.0
3   13.0
5   NaN
2   12.0
7   17.0
8   NaN
1   11.0
9   NaN
EOD

set table $Test
    plot $Data u 1:1:1:2 smooth zsort with points lc variable
unset table
print $Test

# Curve 0 of 1, 9 points
# Curve title: "$Data u 1:1:1:2"
# x y  color type
 1  1  11  i
 2  2  12  i
 3  3  13  i
 4  4  14  i
 5  5  NaN  i
 6  6  16  i
 7  7  17  i
 8  8  NaN  i
 9  9  NaN  i
```

If you take a step back and explain what you are actually trying to do, maybe there is a better answer that doesn't involve zsort at all.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that variable color is written into the table. So, this can be (mis)used for my purpose. Yes, I know that I'm misusing `smooth zsort`. Well, it's the 
 ["old story"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67801386) about sorting datablocks or small data in **gnuplot only**. And I know that you recommended to use an external utility to actually sort the data and write the data into a temporary file on disk and and re-read the file. This here was just another ("stubborn") attempt to avoid external tools and additional files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a truly cumbersome workaround. The basic idea is:

- replace `NaN` with a number `yOut` which is surely out of y-range in order to avoid conflicts with real data
- do `smooth zsort` into a table
- replace `yOut` back to `NaN`

Attempts to shorten the task via [comparing to `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126142/7295599) and/or together within the `smooth zsort` were not successful (so far). So, I had to do a string comparison. I hope there are better solutions.

Actually, using `valid(2)` can shorten the script a bit (check `help valid`).

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.4.0)

```
### workaround for zsort with NaN in data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
4   14.0
6   16.0
3   13.0
5   NaN
2   12.0
7   17.0
9   NaN
1   11.0
8   NaN
EOD

stats $Data u (abs($2)) nooutput
yOut = 1.01*STATS_max + 1   # get a number which is surely out of range

set table $Temp
    plot $Data u 1:(valid(2) ? $2 : yOut):1 smooth zsort
set table $Test
    plot $Temp u 1:($2==yOut ? NaN : $2) w table
unset table
print $Test
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
 1       11
 2       12
 3       13
 4       14
 5       nan
 6       16
 7       17
 8       nan
 9       nan
```