Straight lines appearing around colored patches of a Delaunay-triangulated 2D heatmap plot
Trying to run the @theozh script How to display non-rectangular and ungridded data as a map? I've gotten the very same plot except for straight lines that appear enclosing the various colored parts. I have run the same script (see below) except for the first lines since Windows CoreUtils sort command doesn't work well in my case, so I have generated the sorted $Data file otherwise. But from "# definition of quite a few variables..." on, the script is identical. Does anyone know how to get rid of those enclosing lines? Maybe$Datashould include blank lines between rows ? (that might be the only difference).
### Delaunay triangulation (gnuplot implementation attempt, requires gnuplot 5.4) by theozh
reset session

# get some test data
Random=0        # set to 0 to read data from existing FILE
if (Random) {
    FILE = "tbTriangulationRandom.dat"
    set print FILE
    do for [i=0:99] {
        print sprintf("%g %g %g",x=invnorm(rand(0))*10,y=invnorm(rand(0))*10,x*y)
    }
    set print
}
else {
    FILE = "tbTriangulationTest.dat"  # IT COMES IN THE  LINK PROVIDED BEFORE
}

# sort data by x increasing values and if x is identical by increasing y values

    set format y ""
    set table $Data0
    plot FILE  u 1:2:1 smooth zsort
    set table $Data3
    plot FILE  u 2:2:1 smooth zsort
    set table $Data33
    plot FILE  u 3:2:1 smooth zsort
    unset table

    set print $Data4
    do for [i=1:|$Data0|] {
        print $Data0[i],$Data3[i],$Data33[i]
        if (i<|$Data0|) { if (word($Data0[i],1) ne word($Data0[i+1],1)) { print "" } }
    }
    set print

    set table $Data0
    plot $Data4 u 1:3:3 smooth zsort
    set table $Data3
    plot $Data4 u 3:3:3 smooth zsort
    set table $Data33
    plot $Data4 u 5:3:3 smooth zsort
    unset table
    set print $Data44
    do for [i=1:|$Data0|] { if ($Data4[i] ne "") { print $Data0[i],$Data3[i],$Data33[i];    print " " 
    }}
    set print

    set table $Data
    plot $Data44 u 1:3:5 w table
    unset table
    set format y

# definition of quite a few variables and functions
colX       = 1         # x column
colY       = 2         # y column
colZ       = 3         # z column
N          = |$Data|   # number of points
EDGES      = ''        # list of (inner) edges 
HULL       = ''        # list of hull segments
TRIANGLES  = ''        # list of triangles
HULLPOINTS = ''        # list of hullpoints
array Px[N]            # set point array size
array Py[N]            # set point array size
array Pz[N]            # set point array size

newEdge(p1,p2)      = sprintf(" %d %d ",p1,p2)
Edge(n)             = sprintf(" %s %s ",word(EDGES,2*n-1),word(EDGES,2*n))
EdgeP(n,p)          = int(word(EDGES,2*n-2+p))
changeEdge(n,p1,p2) = (_edge=Edge(n), _pos = strstrt(EDGES,_edge), _pos ? \
                       EDGES[1:_pos-1].newEdge(p1,p2). \
                       EDGES[_pos+strlen(_edge):strlen(EDGES)] : EDGES)

TriangleCount(n)      = words(TRIANGLES)/3
TriangleN(n)          = sprintf(" %s %s %s ", \
                        word(TRIANGLES,3*n-2),word(TRIANGLES,3*n-1),word(TRIANGLES,3*n))
newTriangle(p1,p2,p3) = p1<p2 && p2<p3 ? sprintf(" %d %d %d ",p1,p2,p3) : \
                        p1<p3 && p3<p2 ? sprintf(" %d %d %d ",p1,p3,p2) : \
                        p2<p1 && p1<p3 ? sprintf(" %d %d %d ",p2,p1,p3) : \
                        p2<p3 && p3<p1 ? sprintf(" %d %d %d ",p2,p3,p1) : \
                        p3<p1 && p1<p2 ? sprintf(" %d %d %d ",p3,p1,p2) : \
                                         sprintf(" %d %d %d ",p3,p2,p1)
changeTA(n,p1,p2,p3)  = (TA=TriangleN(n), _pos = strstrt(TRIANGLES,TA), _pos ? \
                         TRIANGLES[1:_pos-1].newTriangle(p1,p2,p3). \
                         TRIANGLES[_pos+strlen(TA):strlen(TRIANGLES)] : TRIANGLES)

TAp(n,p)              = int(word(TRIANGLES,3*n-3+p))
TAx(n,p)              = Px[TAp(n,p)]                  # x-coordinate of point p of triangle n
TAy(n,p)              = Py[TAp(n,p)]                  # y-coordinate of point p of triangle n

HullP(n,p)            = int(word(HULL,2*n-2+p))   # hull segment point number
HScount(n)            = int(words(HULL))/2        # number of hull segments
getHullPoints(n)      = (_tmp = '', sum [_i=1:words(HULL)] ((_s=' '.word(HULL,_i).' ', _tmp = \
                         strstrt(_tmp,_s) ? _tmp : _tmp._s ), 0), _tmp)
removeFromHull(seg)   = (seg, _pos = strstrt(HULL,seg), _pos ? \
                         HULL[1:_pos-1].HULL[_pos+strlen(seg):strlen(HULL)] : HULL)

# orientation of 3 points, either -1=clockwise, 0=collinear, 1=counterclockwise
Orientation(p1,p2,p3) = sgn((Px[p2]-Px[p1])*(Py[p3]-Py[p1]) - (Px[p3]-Px[p1])*(Py[p2]-Py[p1]))

# check for intersection of segment p1-p2 with segment p3-p4, 0=no intersection, 1=intersection
IntersectCheck(p1,p2,p3,p4) = (Orientation(p1,p3,p2)==Orientation(p1,p4,p2)) || \
                                 (Orientation(p3,p1,p4)==Orientation(p3,p2,p4)) ? 0 : 1

Sinus(p1,p2)          = (_dx=Px[p2]-Px[p1], _dy=Py[p2]-Py[p1], _dy/sqrt(_dx**2 + _dy**2))

### Macros for later use
# Creating inner edges datablock macro
CreateEdgeDatablock = '\
set print $EDGES; \
do for [i=1:words(EDGES)/2] { \
    p1 = int(word(EDGES,2*i-1)); \
    p2 = int(word(EDGES,2*i)); \
    print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %d %d",Px[p1],Py[p1],Px[p2]-Px[p1],Py[p2]-Py[p1],p1,p2) \
}; \
set print '

# Creating hull datablock macro
CreateHullDatablock = '\
set print $HULL; \
do for [i=1:words(HULL)/2] { \
    p1 = int(word(HULL,2*i-1)); \
    p2 = int(word(HULL,2*i));   \
    print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %d %d",Px[p1],Py[p1],Px[p2]-Px[p1],Py[p2]-Py[p1],p1,p2) \
}; \
set print '

# plotting everything
PlotEverything = '\
plot $EDGES u 1:2:3:4 w vec lw 1.0 lc "red" nohead, \
      $HULL u 1:2:3:4 w vec lw 1.5 lc "blue" nohead, \
      $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc "black", \
      $Data u 1:2:($0+1) w labels offset 0.5,0.5 '

# put datpoints into arrays
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (Px[int($0)+1]=column(colX),Py[int($0)+1]=column(colY),Pz[int($0)+1]=column(colZ),'') w table
unset table

# get first m>=3 points which are not all collinear
HULL = HULL.newEdge(1,2)                # add first 2 points to hull in any case
do for [p=3:N] {
    if (Orientation(p-2,p-1,p)==0) {    # orientation==0 if collinear
        HULL = HULL.newEdge(p-1,p)
    }    
    else { break }                      # stop if first >=3 non-collinear points found
}
HPcountInit = words(getHullPoints(0))   # get initial number of hull points

# actual plotting starts from here

set offset 1,1,1,1
set key noautotitle
set palette rgb 33,13,10
set rmargin screen 0.8

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc "black", \
        '' u 1:2:($0+1) w labels offset 0.5,0.5

set label 1 at graph 0.02,0.97 "Adding points... "

# loop all data points
do for [p=HPcountInit+1:N] {
    print sprintf("### Adding P%d",p)
    HPlist = getHullPoints(0)
    HPcount = words(HPlist)
    set print $NewConnections   # initalize/empty datablock for new connections
        print ""
    set print
    do for [hpt in HPlist] {          # loop and check all hull points
        hp = int(hpt)
        # print sprintf("Check hull point P%d", hp)
        c = 0
        do for [hs=1:HScount(0)] {               # loop all hull segments
            hp1 = HullP(hs,1)
            hp2 = HullP(hs,2)
            # print sprintf("Check %d-%d with %d-%d", hp1, hp2, hp, p)
            if (p!=hp1 && p!=hp2 && hp!=hp1 && hp!=hp2) {
                c = c || IntersectCheck(hp1,hp2,hp,p)
                if (c) { break }
            }
        }
        if (c==0) {                 # if no intersections with hull
            set print $NewConnections append            # add new connections to datablock
                print sprintf("%g %g", hp, Sinus(p,hp))
            set print
        }
    }
  
    # sort datablock clockwise (a bit cumbersome in gnuplot)
    set table $ConnectSorted
        plot $NewConnections u 1:2:2 smooth zsort    # requires gnuplot 5.4.0
    set table $Dummy
        plot Connect='' $ConnectSorted u (Connect=Connect.sprintf(" %d",$1),'') w table
    unset table
    
    # add new edges
    Ccount = int(words(Connect))
    do for [i=1:Ccount-1] {
        p1 = int(word(Connect,i))
        p2 = int(word(Connect,i+1))
        TRIANGLES = TRIANGLES.sprintf(" %d %d %d ", p1<p2?p1:p2, p2<p1?p1:p2, p)  # numbers in ascending order
        if (i==1) { HULL=HULL.newEdge(p1,p) }
        if (i>1 && i<Ccount) { EDGES = EDGES.newEdge(p1,p) }
        if (i==Ccount-1) { 
            HULL  = HULL.newEdge(p2,p)
        }
        if (p!=HPcountInit+1) {          # remove hull segments, except initial ones
            NewEdge = p1<p2 ? sprintf(" %d %d ",p1,p2) : sprintf(" %d %d ",p2,p1)
            # print sprintf("Remove %s",NewEdge)
            HULL = removeFromHull(NewEdge)
            EDGES = EDGES.NewEdge
            @CreateEdgeDatablock
            @CreateHullDatablock
            @PlotEverything
        }
    }
}


# flip diagonal of a quadrangle if Det(p1,p2,p3,p4) and Orientation(p1,p2,p3) have the same sign
#
m11(p1,p4) = Px[p1]-Px[p4]
m21(p2,p4) = Px[p2]-Px[p4]
m31(p3,p4) = Px[p3]-Px[p4]

m12(p1,p4) = Py[p1]-Py[p4]
m22(p2,p4) = Py[p2]-Py[p4]
m32(p3,p4) = Py[p3]-Py[p4]

m13(p1,p4) = (Px[p1]-Px[p4])**2 + (Py[p1]-Py[p4])**2
m23(p2,p4) = (Px[p2]-Px[p4])**2 + (Py[p2]-Py[p4])**2
m33(p3,p4) = (Px[p3]-Px[p4])**2 + (Py[p3]-Py[p4])**2

Det(p1,p2,p3,p4) = m11(p1,p4)*(m22(p2,p4)*m33(p3,p4) - m32(p3,p4)*m23(p2,p4)) + \
                   m12(p1,p4)*(m23(p2,p4)*m31(p3,p4) - m33(p3,p4)*m21(p2,p4)) + \
                   m13(p1,p4)*(m21(p2,p4)*m32(p3,p4) - m31(p3,p4)*m22(p2,p4))

# create triangle data
set print $Triangles
    do for [i=1:TriangleCount(0)] {
        print sprintf("%g %g",TAx(i,1),TAy(i,1))
        print sprintf("%g %g",TAx(i,2),TAy(i,2))
        print sprintf("%g %g",TAx(i,3),TAy(i,3))
        print sprintf("%g %g",TAx(i,1),TAy(i,1))
        print ""
    }
unset print

@CreateEdgeDatablock
@CreateHullDatablock
@PlotEverything

set label 1 "Flipping diagonals... "

###
# loop edges and check if need to flip. If on edge was flipped, start over again.
flip = 0
flipCount = 0
flippedAtLeastOnce = 1
while (flippedAtLeastOnce) {
    flippedAtLeastOnce=0
    do for [e=1:words(EDGES)/2] {               # loop all inner edges
        # find the 2 triangles with this edge
        p1 = EdgeP(e,1)
        p2 = EdgeP(e,2)
        found = 0
        do for [t=1:TriangleCount(0)] {         # loop all triangles
            tap1 = TAp(t,1)
            tap2 = TAp(t,2)
            tap3 = TAp(t,3)
            p = p1==tap1 ? p2==tap2 ? tap3 : p2==tap3 ? tap2 : 0 : p1==tap2 ? p2==tap3 ? tap1 : 0 : 0
            # print sprintf("%d %d %d: %d",tap1,tap2,tap3,p)
            if (p!=0) {
                if (found==1) { 
                    ta2=t; p4=p; 
                    flip  = sgn(Det(p1,p2,p3,p4))==Orientation(p1,p2,p3)
                    flippedAtLeastOnce = flippedAtLeastOnce || flip
                    if (flip) {
                        flipCount = flipCount+1
                        print sprintf("Flip % 3d: %d-%d with %d-%d",flipCount,p1,p2,p3,p4)
                        EDGES     = changeEdge(e,p3,p4)
                        TRIANGLES = changeTA(ta1,p1,p3,p4)
                        TRIANGLES = changeTA(ta2,p2,p3,p4)
                        @CreateEdgeDatablock
                        @CreateHullDatablock
                        @PlotEverything
                        break           # start over again
                    }
                }
                if (found==0) { ta1=t; p3=p; found=1}
            }
        }
    }
}
###

# create quadrangles datablock
Center2x(p1,p2)    = (Px[p1]+Px[p2])/2.          # x-center of 2 points
Center2y(p1,p2)    = (Py[p1]+Py[p2])/2.          # y-center of 2 points
Center3x(p1,p2,p3) = (Px[p1]+Px[p2]+Px[p3])/3.   # x-center between 3 points
Center3y(p1,p2,p3) = (Py[p1]+Py[p2]+Py[p3])/3.   # x-center between 3 points

set print $QUADRANGLES
    do for [i=1:TriangleCount(0)] {
        do for [p=0:2] {
            z = Pz[TAp(i,p+1)]
            tap1 = TAp(i,p+1)
            tap2 = TAp(i,(p+1)%3+1)
            tap3 = TAp(i,(p+2)%3+1)
            print sprintf("%g %g %g", Px[tap1], Py[tap1], z)
            print sprintf("%g %g %g", Center2x(tap1,tap2), Center2y(tap1,tap2), z)
            print sprintf("%g %g %g", Center3x(tap1,tap2,tap3), Center3y(tap1,tap2,tap3), z)
            print sprintf("%g %g %g", Center2x(tap1,tap3), Center2y(tap1,tap3), z)
            print sprintf("%g %g %g", Px[tap1], Py[tap1], z)
            print ''
        }

    }
set print

set label 1 "Coloring areas."

plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 w filledcurves closed lc palette, \
     $EDGES u 1:2:3:4 w vec lw 1.0 lc "grey" nohead, \
     $HULL u 1:2:3:4 w vec lw 1.5 lc "blue" nohead, \
     $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc palette
### end of code```




Please always show what commands you used. In general no one can say what went wrong with your script if you do not show the script.  I am guessing perhaps you need to add "set pm3d noborder" but that's only a guess.

Without having tested or looked to your modifications in detail yet, a wild guess would be that sorting data by two values (i.e. first x and then y) via smooth zsort does not work properly under Windows. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67801386/7295599

Indeed I already checked that very same link to use the "order preserving" part of your script to generate my sorted file (I made a trivial 3D extension of it that I will post when I'll have 50 points), rather than with CoreUtils sort that for some reason didn't work well. Other than that, I've changed not even a comma of your triangulation script. Your 2D sort script works very well under windows, I don't think that's the reason of those mysterious enclosing lines around each colored patch.

If this could give a hint... once the script has been run, trying plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 w polygons (with or without lc palette) gives precisely those surrounding segments exclusively; so the goal would be to have plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 w filledcurves lc palette minus plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 w polygons

@Ethan I tried your idea and had a look at the manual (indeed what is read under "border" seems the right thing to do) where they suggest to use set pm3d border retrace too as an alternative. But none of them makes the least effect.

OK, I downloaded your entire script and ran it.  I too get borders around the colored areas.  As the previous comment suggests, you can remove these by changing the plot command to plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 w polygons lc palette fs solid, or alternatively change it to plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 w filledcurves lc palette lt nodraw.  I do not know why the lines are appearing as if a colored border is requested :-/

Perfect ! Thx ! If you know how to give you a vote... here in the comments sections I don't know how to do so

Let's condense this down to the nub of the matter:
$QUADRANGLES << EOD
-24.4571 1.79031 -43.7857
-21.0939 1.52621 -43.7857
-17.9859 2.84816 -43.7857
-18.1135 3.64119 -43.7857
-24.4571 1.79031 -43.7857

-17.7308 1.2621 -22.378
-14.7503 3.37709 -22.378
-17.9859 2.84816 -22.378
-21.0939 1.52621 -22.378
-17.7308 1.2621 -22.378

-11.7699 5.49208 -64.641
-18.1135 3.64119 -64.641
-17.9859 2.84816 -64.641
-14.7503 3.37709 -64.641
-11.7699 5.49208 -64.641

-24.4571 1.79031 -43.7857
-21.0939 1.52621 -43.7857
-18.5289 -1.54692 -43.7857
-18.9279 -2.95143 -43.7857
-24.4571 1.79031 -43.7857

-17.7308 1.2621 -22.378
-15.5648 -3.21554 -22.378
-18.5289 -1.54692 -22.378
-21.0939 1.52621 -22.378
-17.7308 1.2621 -22.378

-13.3988 -7.69317 103.08
-18.9279 -2.95143 103.08
-18.5289 -1.54692 103.08
-15.5648 -3.21554 103.08
-13.3988 -7.69317 103.08

-24.4571 1.79031 -43.7857
-19.7591 11.5522 -43.7857
-17.096 9.53213 -43.7857
-18.1135 3.64119 -43.7857
-24.4571 1.79031 -43.7857

-15.0611 21.314 -321.012
-13.4155 13.403 -321.012
-17.096 9.53213 -321.012
-19.7591 11.5522 -321.012
-15.0611 21.314 -321.012
EOD

plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 with filledcurves closed lc palette

The plot has a border around each quadrangle because the program's default fill style is equivalent to set style fill empty border.  The "empty" part is superseded by plot with filledcurves because it makes zero sense to not fill a filled curve.  But the "border" part is honored.  You can remove the border by changing the global default fill style:
set style fill solid noborder

or you can put this in the plot command instead
plot $QUADRANGLES u 1:2:3 with filledcurves fillstyle solid noborder fc palette

In new-ish gnuplot versions, with filledcurves closed can be replace by with polygons.
For completeness I'll add that even if the fill style does specify a border, you can make the border invisible by using the "nodraw" line type.
